# Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic not finding location W7

Tags: c#, file-copying

Ok, So at my job we do a lot of formats, and to save time I thought I would make a simple c# console app that would copy the users data to a usb or portable hard drive to save us time.
When copying the contents in the pictures folder
 `string SourcePathPIC = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);`
There are no problems, however when trying to copy the music folders contents, It tells me that it `Can't find path`, but when trying the same program on Windows 10, it works.
 There is the music part of the Cs file.

```
      //MUSIC
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading Music...");

                string SourcePathMUSIC = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);

                string DestinationPathMUSIC = DRIVELOCATION + @"\DOWNLOADEDDATA\music";
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePathMUSIC, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePathMUSIC, DestinationPathMUSIC));
                }

                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePathMUSIC, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePathMUSIC, DestinationPathMUSIC), true);
                    Console.WriteLine(newPath);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Music Downloaded");
                Console.ForegroundColor = CONSOLECOLOUR;
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }

            catch
            {
                string SourcePathMUSIC = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic);
                string DestinationPathMUSIC = DRIVELOCATION + @"\DOWNLOADEDDATA\music";
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePathMUSIC, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePathMUSIC, DestinationPathMUSIC));
                }

                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePathMUSIC, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                {
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePathMUSIC, DestinationPathMUSIC), true);
                    Console.WriteLine(newPath);
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.WriteLine("Unable To Copy Some Files, User Has Proctection On Music, You Will Need To Manually Copy The Remaining");
            }
            Console.ForegroundColor = CONSOLECOLOUR;
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.ForegroundColor = CONSOLECOLOUR;
            Console.WriteLine("                       DOWNLOAD COMPLETE....");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var CONSOLECOLOR = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ForegroundColor = CONSOLECOLOR;
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            //Environment.Exit(1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

If you need to see the pictures section, let me know and I can update my question, I didn't add it because i didn't want to add too much code.
Thanks!

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic)` works fine on my W7 machine. Are you sure the folder exists and/or you have permission to it? Try running the code as Administrator.

Comment: @keyboardP just tried using Administrator mode and stepping through the code, it looks like it is getting the path `G:\\DOWLOADEDDATA\music\Kalimba.mp3`, I think this is odd because all I have done is change the `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures` to `MyMusic`

Comment: i remove one of the dashes in the `G:\\DOWLOADEDDATA\music\Kalimba.mp3` still giving the same error without or with the extra `/` tried un-ticking the `read only` of the music folders properties, still no go.

Comment: Weird, so i change the Framework from 3.5 to 4.6.1 and then back to 3.5 and now it is working, even with the same code...... strange.

Comment: Maybe it was on 3.5 Client Profile before?

Comment: very strange indeed, I tried it on 3.5 Client Profile to see what it would do and it worked, maybe i wasn't holding my tongue the right way.

Comment: Haha one of those quirks I guess. Probably worth posting that as an answer since it seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: no worries, cheers again mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm posting my answer just in case someone else comes across the same issue I had.
I ended up changing the framework from 3.5 to 4.6.1 compiling and then switching the framework back to 3.5 and hooray, it works!.....WEIRD! since i did't change any code.